# Highlight the user name in a comment of an answer when the author is the one that posted that answer

Tags: feature-request, comments

Currently, the site highlights the user who posted the question whenever that same user posts a comment or an answer:

> [image: User who asked the question is highlighted in comments]

Can we do something similar for the user commenting on his/her own answer?

I am suggesting to turn this:

> [image: User who answered the question is not highlighted]

Into something like this:

> [image: User who answered the question is highlighted]

I think this would be useful to, for example, see what are the points the person is making in the comments, to complement their own answer. You would mentally associate the comment to the person who gave that answer without having to look at the username, like you do when the author of the question is highlighted.

Comment: Currently, the question asker's name is also highlighted on the answers as well. How would you differentiate the two of them, in the event of a question asker and answer writer both commenting on an answer?

Comment: @Félix see the last image. I'm proposing that the username is highlighted in a different way (only outline, not whole background). So it's highlighted with less emphasis too.

Comment: the image also shows the comment from the author of the question, and you would clearly diffentiate: author-of-question / author-of-answer / other-user

Comment: yeah... I looked at the images. I'm not really convinced there would be any sane way not to be confused needlessly about this. I'll admit I do not see the need for that in the first place.

Comment: I don't think this would be confusing in any way.

Comment: Well. There are two names, both of which have two different shades. How is it evident which one is which? I mean, I currently know that the shadow means op, but I'll literally forget what particular shade means op vs answerer.

Comment: it's evident that the commenter is the person who gave that answer because the username in that answer would be highlighted in the same way (outline), and only the comments in that answer that are highlighted that way (outline) are from that user

Comment: maybe I made it seem complicated because I erased the names in the image...

Comment: Similar to this, I made [a userscript](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/CommentUserColours.user.js) to follow users in long comment threads, e.g.: [screenshot](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/master/images/Screenshot_2018-07-05_100726.png)

Comment: That outline you're showing can be tough to see on some screens (even the existing shading can be difficult to see).  When viewing the comments to an answer, it is easy enough to see who the answerer is so a specific highlight brings little if any benefit.  For the question asker, it can be a _long_ way away up the screen so that highlight is helpful.

Comment: Declined feature request on MSE: [Highlight comments from answer author, in addition to question author](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19574)

Comment: @honk Thanks, I was able to make a userscript based on that answer. I think I'll post it as an answer here, in case someone wants to try it.

Answer (score 4):

So, I made a userscript (based on [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19574)) in case someone wants to try it on any of the Stack Exchange sites.

```
// Using jQuery

function colorAnswerer() {
    let co = $('.post-signature.owner').css('background-color');
    let aa = $('.answercell');
    aa.each(function() {
        var as = $(this).find('.user-details a')
        var a = as.last();
        var b = as.filter(i => i < as.length - 1);
        var l = '2px solid'; // can also try dashed and dotted
        a.parents('.post-signature').css('border', l + ' ' + co);
        b.parents('.post-signature').css('border', '2px solid transparent');
        var x = a.text();
        var cm = $('.comment-user', this.parentNode)
        cm.each(function(i) {
            if ($(this).text() == x) {
                $(this).css('border', l + ' ' + co);
            }
        });
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.comments').bind('DOMNodeInserted DOMNodeRemoved', function(event) {
        if (event.type == 'DOMNodeInserted' || event.type == 'DOMNodeInserted') {
            colorAnswerer();
        }
    });
});

colorAnswerer();
```